# Zoom in and out on photos inside uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, pinchzoom

I want to use imageview with zoom functionality with multiple images inside uiscrollview.I have tried scrollview inside scrollview but that could not sort out my problem.As I want to scroll between photos and also zoom those photos.

Comment: Put your tried code in your question and explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple Github project that might be what you're after. Check it out here:
https://github.com/twomedia/TMImageZoom

I achieved this by creating a class that handled the gesture state changes. I then create a UIImageView on the window and position/size it to the original image view creating the effect of the user zooming the imageView. Here's a small snippet from the above link:

```
-(void) gestureStateChanged:(id)gesture withZoomImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView {

// Insure user is passing correct UIPinchGestureRecognizer class.
if (![gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    NSLog(@"(TMImageZoom): Must be using a UIPinchGestureRecognizer, currently you're using a: %@",[gesture class]);
    return;
}

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *theGesture = gesture;

// Prevent animation issues if currently animating reset.
if (isAnimatingReset) {
    return;
}

// Reset zoom if state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
if (theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
    [self resetImageZoom];
}

// Ignore other views trying to start zoom if already zooming with another view
if (isHandlingGesture && hostImageView != imageView) {
    NSLog(@"(TMImageZoom): 'gestureStateChanged:' ignored since this imageView isnt being tracked");
    return;
}

// Start handling gestures if state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and not already handling gestures.
if (!isHandlingGesture && theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    isHandlingGesture = YES;

    // Set Host ImageView
    hostImageView = imageView;
    imageView.hidden = YES;

    // Convert local point to window coordinates
    CGPoint point = [imageView convertPoint:imageView.frame.origin toView:nil];
    startingRect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

    // Post Notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TMImageZoom_Started_Zoom_Notification object:nil];

    // Get current window and set starting vars
    UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    firstCenterPoint = [theGesture locationInView:currentWindow];

    // Init zoom ImageView
    currentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageView.image];
    currentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [currentImageView setFrame:startingRect];
    [currentWindow addSubview:currentImageView];
}

// Reset if user removes a finger (Since center calculation would cause image to jump to finger as center. Maybe this could be improved later)
if (theGesture.numberOfTouches < 2) {
    [self resetImageZoom];
    return;
}

// Update scale & center
if (theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", theGesture.scale);

    // Calculate new image scale.
    CGFloat currentScale = currentImageView.frame.size.width / startingRect.size.width;
    CGFloat newScale = currentScale * theGesture.scale;
    [currentImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(currentImageView.frame.origin.x, currentImageView.frame.origin.y, startingRect.size.width*newScale, startingRect.size.height*newScale)];

    // Calculate new center
    UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    int centerXDif = firstCenterPoint.x-[theGesture locationInView:currentWindow].x;
    int centerYDif = firstCenterPoint.y-[theGesture locationInView:currentWindow].y;
    currentImageView.center = CGPointMake((startingRect.origin.x+(startingRect.size.width/2))-centerXDif, (startingRect.origin.y+(startingRect.size.height/2))-centerYDif);

    // Reset gesture scale
    theGesture.scale = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: What if I want to stop the image to zoom out after user lifted finger.As of now if the user lifts finger then the image zooms out

Comment: And if I add this gesture to scrollview with multiple imageviews then it is zooming the last image.Even if I add this gesture to all UIImageviews that are inside scrollview then this is zooming the last image in the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done it before try this.

> https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer